# Randomly replace cells in a numpy array without replacement

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 25 x 25 numpy array filled with 0s. I want to randomly replace 0s within the array with 1s, with the number of 0s to be replaced defined by the user and ranging from 1 to 625. How can I do this without replacement becoming an issue given there are two coordinate values, x and y?

Code for generating a 25 x 25 array:

```
 import numpy as np
 Array = np.zeros((25,25))
```

Expected result on a 4 x 4 array:

Before

```
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
```

After (replace 1)

```
0,0,0,0
0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
```

After (replace 16)

```
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python so I haven't got far. My current configuration uses np.random.randint(low = 0, high =24, size = n), with a set of x and y coordinates defined via this method. I then loop through my array like so:  for x,y in zip(PositionX, PositionY): Array[x][y] = 1  but this does not prevent the same coordinates being selected more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes:**

- One may generate a unique sequence of random integers from 0 to 624, and mutate the corresponding element of the ***flattened*** array according to the generated sequence. Working with the flattened array, in this specific case, enables the development of a (relatively) concise code.
- One can use `np.random.choice` together with the argument `replace=False` to generate a non-repetitive sequence of random numbers. You can see more information on [NumPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

---

Here is one of the solutions for a case with a 2D array of the size of 5x5 that undergoes 5 mutations:

```
import numpy as np

dim = 5     #<========== size of each axis of array -- in your case, it would be 25
num_mut = 5 #<========== number of mutations -- in your case it would be an integer from 0 to 624

Array = np.zeros((dim,dim))
Array_flat = Array.flatten()
print('before mutation:')
print(Array)

ind_mut = np.random.choice(dim*dim, size=num_mut, replace=False).tolist()
Array_flat[ind_mut]=1
Array_mut = Array_flat.reshape(Array.shape)

print('\nafter mutation:')
print(Array_mut)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import random

import numpy as np

SIZE = 25

howmany = 500

array = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE), dtype=int)
xyset = set()

for i in range(SIZE):
    for j in range(SIZE):
        xyset.add((i, j))

for num in range(howmany):
    xy = random.choice(list(xyset))
    array[xy[0], xy[1]] = 1

    xyset.discard(xy)

print(array)
```

Comment: This will replace 25 elements, but not the full 625 in a 25 x 25 array.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I misread the question. Code above now edited to work on the full array - using a set of tuples with the x, y coordinates which are randomly chosen,